# Fastify: Is it possible to access envs registered in one file via fastify-env in another file?

Tags: node.js, fastify

Here's my problem. I want to load the envs from .env file and use those values in the db connection string.

So I'm trying to do the setup by creating two setup files: One that loads the envs, the other that uses them to form the connection string and establish the db connection.

I'm trying to separate the setup from the app.js file. Here's what I have (app.js):

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

const initialize = async () => {
  fastify.register(require('./setup/envs'))
  await fastify.after() // important as it waits for plugin to stop loading
  console.log('config is: ', fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME) // works. 
  fastify.register(require('./setup/db'));
}

initialize();
console.log('fastify config is: ', fastify.config) // gives undefined
fastify.get('/hello', (req, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})

fastify.listen(3000, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
})
```

My envs.js file is as follows:

```
const fastify = require('fastify');
const fastifyPlugin = require('fastify-plugin');
const fastifyEnv = require('fastify-env');

const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: [ 'PORT', 'DATABASE_USERNAME', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME', 'JWT_SECRET' ],
  properties: {
    PORT: {
      type: 'string',
      default: 3000
    },
    DATABASE_USERNAME: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    DATABASE_NAME: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    JWT_SECRET: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}

const options = {
  confKey: 'config', // optional, default: 'config'
  schema: schema,
  dotenv: true
}

async function envConnector (fastify) {
  fastify.register(fastifyEnv, options)
}

module.exports =  fastifyPlugin(envConnector);
```

and here's my db.js:

```
const fastify = require('fastify');
const fastifyPlugin = require('fastify-plugin');
const fastifyPostgres = require('fastify-postgres');

console.log('from db.js', fastify.config); // undefined

const dbUser = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_USERNAME)
const dbPassword = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
const dbHost = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_HOST);
const dbName = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME);

async function dbConnector (fastify, options) {
  fastify.register(fastifyPostgres, {
    connectionString: `postgres://${dbUser}@${dbHost}/${dbName}`
  })
}
// Wrapping a plugin function with fastify-plugin exposes the decorators
// and hooks, declared inside the plugin to the parent scope.
module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbConnector);
```

unfortunately, the console.log in db.js gives undefined. Is there no way for me to access the envs in the db.js file?

Also, I tried to console.log the config outside the initialize function in app.js and also got undefined.

How do I access the env vars throughout my app?

Comment: You can't access those values until you are inside the `dbConnector` function.  The global fastify instance is not encapsulated with your previously registered plugin for config, you need to use the fastify instance passed into the `dbConnector` plugin function. https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Encapsulation/

Answer (score 2):

Fastify does NOT set any global values. So, snippets like this will never work:

```
//WRONG EXAMPLE
const fastify = require('fastify');
console.log('from db.js', fastify.config); // undefined
```

A simpler way to accomplish your need is:

```
const initialize = async () => {
  const fastify = require('fastify')()
  await fastify.register(require('./setup/envs'))
  console.log('config is: ', fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME) // works. 
  fastify.register(require('./setup/db'));
  return fastify
}

initialize()
  .then((app)=>{
    console.log('fastify config is: ', app.config)
  })
```

And then:

```js
async function dbConnector (fastify, options) {
  // I'm using the fastify input argument
  const dbUser = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_USERNAME)
  const dbPassword = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
  const dbHost = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_HOST);
  const dbName = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME);

  fastify.register(fastifyPostgres, {
    connectionString: `postgres://${dbUser}@${dbHost}/${dbName}`
  })
}

module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbConnector);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I can access fasty.config within the dbConnector function and not outside of it after registering the env plugin by using `.after()` as shown here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/Plugins.md#handle-the-scope.

Anyways, these are the changes I made.

in app.js:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger: true})

fastify.register(require('./setup/envs'))
       .after(err => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          fastify.register(require('./setup/db'))
       })

fastify.get('/hello', (req, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})


const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.ready()
    fastify.listen(3000)
  } catch (e) {
    fastify.log.error(e)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start();
```

and in db.js:

```
const fastifyPlugin = require('fastify-plugin');
const fastifyPostgres = require('fastify-postgres');


// can use process.env here 
const dbUser = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME)
const dbPassword = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
const dbHost = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DATABASE_HOST);
const dbName = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DATABASE_NAME);

async function dbConnector (fastify, options) {
  // or use fasty.config here
  //   ...
  // const dbName = encodeURIComponent(fastify.config.DATABASE_NAME);

  fastify.register(fastifyPostgres, {
    connectionString: `postgres://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@${dbHost}/${dbName}`
  })
}
// Wrapping a plugin function with fastify-plugin exposes the decorators
// and hooks, declared inside the plugin to the parent scope.
module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbConnector);
```

Not sure why, for example, `process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME` gives me the value but `fastify.config.DATABASE_USERNAME` doesn't but oh wells.